# Using find results when directories have spaces in their names

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to change the permissions of all the subdirectories by making a simple bash `for` loop:

```
for dir in `find . -type d`; do chmod 755 "$dir"; done
```

however, it complains about non-existing directories. By simply printing the directory names from the loop (replacing `chmod 755 "$dir"` with `echo "$dir"`) I've worked out that the problem occurs when a directory has spaces in its name. What happens is that the `for` loop splits the results of `find` on every newline **and** space.

I'd like to somehow make it split the results **only** according to newlines and ignore the spaces. The double quotes should make sure that the string reaches `chmod` as one argument. How do I change the splitting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual solution to this problem is:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

The `-print0` argument causes the output filenames to be nul-terminated and the `-0` / `-null` argument to xargs tells it to read such a format.

So in your case...

```
$ find . -type d -a -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
```

You don't actually need the shell loop at all.

Comment: OK, that is really nice :). But I've seen some commands panic when the list of arguments is too long. Is that something that could be solved using the -n parameter to xargs?

Comment: Also, what happens when the command only takes one argument at a time? I realize this is a bit broader than the main question, but still.

Comment: The limit on # of arguments is usually the kernel's exec limit, which *xargs* checks and automatically handles by running the command more than once. It can also handle a command that really allows only 1, use: *xargs -n 1*

Comment: Work in Mac OS terminal

Answer (score 4):

Here are some more options for your toolkit. If you just have a single command to execute on groups of files/directories, `find` can do it directly:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

If the command can only work on one file/directory at a time, use `\;` instead of `+` to run once for each item:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

And if you need to do something complex (i.e. several commands), you can make a safe version of the loop:

```
while IFS= read -r -u3 -d $'\0' dir; do
    sudo chown gkudelis "$dir"
    chmod 755 "$dir"
    touch "$dir/.perms_reset"
done 3< <(find /tmp -type f -print0)
```

Note that this uses a redirect from a process substitution (`<(...)`) instead of a pipe to avoid running the loop in a subshell; this is a bash-only feature, so you must start the script with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`. Also, it does the redirect to fd 3 instead of stdin, so if anything inside the loop tries to read from stdin it won't get confused. Also, be sure to use double-quotes around all references to the loop variable (`"$dir"` in this example) to protect spaces in it. See [BashFAQ #020](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for more details.

Comment: More useful answer than the accepted one, since it works for a wider number of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead (using *builtins*,  requires `bash --version` >= 4) :

```
shopt -s globstar
for dir in **/*/; do
    chmod 0755 "${dir%/}"
done
```

Comment: Note that this requires `bash` 4 or later.